# Mass Distribution to turn Hanging Chain into Parabola

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, variational-calculus, statics

I've learned recently about how a uniform chain hanging between two points will form a catenary curve (of the form $a \cdot \cosh (\frac{x}{a})$), and I reflected on the fact that this is only because of the fact that the chain has a uniform mass density. I then reasoned that a chain with a non-uniform mass density would have another shape when hung between two poles. Specifically, there must exist some mass distribution such that the hanging chain would form a parabola. However, I am unsure how to find this mass distribution. Does anyone know what this mass distribution is, or how I would go in the right direction of finding it?

Comment: I think you can write out the differential equation governing the rope, and work backward by substituting vertical displacement $y(x) = x^2$ to the equation and solve for $\mu(x)$ ?

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but don't I need to give the mass density as a function of arc-length? Like can I have the mass density be as a function of the x-coordinate of the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/parabolas_and_catenaries.htm), for example, one obtains a parabolic shape from a hanging chain if the vertical load is constant regardless of the slope of the chain. The reason is that a horizontal force balance anywhere gives $T\cos\theta=T_0$, where $T$ is the tension, $\theta$ is the angle with the horizontal, and $T_0$ is the tension at the (symmetric) center at the origin. A vertical force balance anywhere gives $T\sin\theta=wx$, where $w$ is the weight per horizontal distance. Dividing the latter by the former, we obtain $\tan\theta=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{wx}{T_0}$, which we can integrate to obtain a parabola $y\sim x^2$.

Therefore, the reference mass density at the center of the chain should be reduced elsewhere by the factor $\cos\theta$ so that a sharply sloped chain doesn't weigh any more than a horizontal chain. You can verify that if the parabola is expressed by $y=ax^2$, where $a=\frac{y_0}{x_0^2}$ refers to the attachment point at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\tan^{-1}(2ax)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y_0x}{x_0^2}\right)$. The mass density should therefore by adjusted by
$$\cos\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y_0x}{x_0^2}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4y_0^2x^2}{x_0^4}+1}}=\frac{x_0^2}{\sqrt{4y_0^2x^2+x_0^4}}$$ relative to the mass density at the center.